# How to convert .jar or .class to .dex file?

Tags: java, android, dex, dx

I'm going to edit the Opera Mini v6.5 server because it is blocked in our country.

Now I have unpacked the ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`.apk` file extracted `classes.Dex` then converted it via `dex2jar.bat`, now modified the server.

My problem is I want to repack the `.jar` or `.class` to `classes.Dex`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here is a solution that was helpful in my case...

Suppose .jar file sits in "c:\temp\in.jar". In command prompt window cd to ..\android-sdk\platform-tools.
To get .apk execute:

```
dx --dex --output="c:\temp\app.apk" "c:\temp\in.jar"
```

To get .dex file execute:

```
dx --dex --output="c:\temp\dx.dex" "c:\temp\in.jar"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is because I'm on OS X but my dx binary is in sdk/build-tools/<version> instead of sdk/platform-tools.

Comment: I run this line: 21.1.1 congba$ dx --dex --output="/Volumes/DATA/Dev_Tools/ba.dex" "/Volumes/DATA/Dev_Tools/gdx.jar" and get error: -bash: dx: command not found

Comment: @RichardFung Same with Linux

Comment: i got no classfiles specified

Answer (score 3):

For mac, the dx command tool is stored in  different directory as said in the top answer. Here is how you do it in mac:

```
   exampleName$ /Users/exampleName/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/dx --dex --output="/Users/exampleName/Downloads/classes-dex2jar.jar" "/Users/exampleName/Downloads/name.dex"
```

**More detailed explanation:**

- The dx tool is stored in the android SDK, but in a different directory on macs, the path for a mac is `/Users/exampleName/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/`
- The command is the same for windows and mac, the path is just different
- The command for both platforms is  `dx --dex--output="c:\temp\app.apk" "c:\temp\in.jar"`
- The tool may take a few minutes to produce the dex file

If it's still not working for some reason, make sure you are following these requirements:

[image]

I know this is late, but I had to figure this out on my own after hours of trial and error—hope it helps some other mac user

Answer (score 1):

To avoid downloading the entire Android Studio:
You can go to [command-tools download](https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools) and extract the folder.  Then go into it and find your `sdkmanager` tool.  Then on your command-line type `sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.1"`.  You can select which version of build-tools is appropriate depending on the java version you are working with.  This will download it into the root directory of your command-line tools.  Go into this folder and you should see the `dx` tool.  Then you can type `dx --dex --output="nameoffile.dex" nameoffile.jar`.

A little extra note:  If you are trying to convert a massive jar you might get a `OUT OF MEMORY` error.  In this case you just pass the JVM the increase heap option `dx -JXmx256m ...`.

Comment: Unfortunaly, `dx -JXmx256m --dex --output="name.dex" "name.jar"` doesn't work(No command specified).

Comment: You should write one file at a time

Answer (score 0):

To dexify a jar file, you would use dx.bat inside of your sdk's platform-tools folder. You can also look at the -dex task inside of the build.xml file inside of your tools\ant folder in your SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer now i have another problem i used this command line in run but nothing happened just opened and closed dx.bat

e:\users\sadra\desktop\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\dx –dex –output=classes.dex –locals=full –positions=lines classes.jar

and i didn't find build.XML in that folder now what should i do???

Comment: Try looking in e:\users\sadra\desktop\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml. You could also just use ant (by setting the properties needed by the -dex step) to do your conversion.

Comment: thanks a lot again but I'm no Ob and didn't understand what u said
i didn't find build.xml again
also another item how about using smali and how to ???

Comment: Are you sure you got no error when you ran the dx command? If there was no error, you should see a classes.dex file sitting in the directory somewhere.

Comment: here is the link what i see after using that it says no command
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/?418z8pbjhoo3ch4)

Comment: again hi
i have updated my sdk and build.xml apeared
I changed my command line to this
C:\GOOGLE\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\dx ––dex ––output=classes.dex –locals=full ––positions=lines jsdt.jar
now after taking a moment there is an error :5error ; aborting

so what should i do now??

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what that error means. Are you sure it's not giving you something more helpful?

Comment: You can do some research on the ANT build system. The file should be in the directory I pointed you to. It has the code necessary to run a dex target that should convert a jar to a dex / apk file.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need the [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/), it allows you to repack and resign a apk, without the need to get in to running dx and aapt yourself.

[Here's an article](http://androidforums.com/esteem-all-things-root/520917-guide-how-properly-decompile-recompile-apks-apktool.html) on how to unpack and repack