# URLClassLoader working on Java but not in Android

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, urlclassloader

My URLClassLoader implementation seems to only work on pc, but not on Android.

```
try {

        Class<?> loadedClass = new URLClassLoader(
                new URL[] { new File("http://10.0.2.2/myphpfile.php").toURI().toURL() })
                .loadClass("MyClass");

        IInterface inter = (IInterface) loadedClass.getConstructor(
                String.class).newInstance("Hello");
        if (inter != null)
            System.out.println(inter.doSomething(2));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It just works fine, but on android I´m getting

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass

Internet Permission is set.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get it working?

Comment: checkout sample code in this project: https://github.com/gelldur/msc-thesis/tree/master/project/SecureMe/app/src/main/java/drozd/dawid/dexode/com/secureme

Answer (score 4):

Use [`DexClassLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) instead of URLClassLoader.

First you need your jar file to include a classes.dex, there's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101543/2448070):

```
dx --dex --output="JarProjectWithDex.jar" "JarProject.jar"
```

And then you simply replace your URLClassLoader with a DexClassLoader and continue the same way:

```
File jarFile = new File("/data/JarProjectWithDex.jar");
DexClassLoader loader = new DexClassLoader(jarFile.getPath(), getFilesDir().getPath(), null, this.getClassLoader());
Class<?> classToLoad = Class.forName("zordon.MegaZords", true, loader);
```