# Is it possible to convert JVM prepared jar file to Dalvik compatible jar?

Tags: java, android, jar, executable-jar, dalvik

I have have a .jar application compatible to JVM. How can I convert it to Dalvik compatible jar file?

I have come to know that using Java decompiler, I can convert all byte codes inside jar to source code. Is it the only option that I compile the source code with dx tool to make it Dalvik compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dx` tool as described in [How to convert .jar or .class to .dex file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348144/how-to-convert-jar-or-class-to-dex-file). Even if you are able to accomplish this, you will still not be able to simply run the dexed JAR file on an Android device as Android uses a different model than desktop Java does.