# How to make ide in Android like AIDE to compile android project in android phone itself

Tags: android, ide

As I know there is a Software (AIDE) in android that can compile android projects to APK in android phones.
My question is how this works? Is it possible to make DEX file in android devices and pack it in APK?

Comment: The AIDE team cross-compiled the Android development toolchain themselves, AFAIK. If you are an expert, you can do the same thing, presumably. There is nothing officially supported for this.

Comment: Does anyone knows that what is the job of "android.jar" file in "android-sdk\platforms\android-23" ??

Comment: It contains stub implementations of the Android SDK's public API (classes, methods, etc.), sufficient to allow `javac` to compile source code that references that public Android API.

Comment: I think its time to cross-compile the toolchain :) i found this thread for start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348144/how-to-convert-jar-or-class-to-dex-file

Comment: Since Android looks like an Apache license, I'm not sure if compiling an Android project on an Android operating system will violate a particular license?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create a basic level Java/Xml Android App using AIDE.

**Step:1**: Prerequisites

> Install [AIDE from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) on your Android device (all Android versions from 2.2 are supported) and start it. AIDE comes bundled with a mobile version of the Android SDK, so there is no need to install anything else.

**Step:2**: Creating the App Project

> "When you start AIDE for the first time in expert mode you will see the "Create new Project" dialog. If you have already opened a project the dialog will not show, but you can invoke it from AIDE's integrated file browser by choosing "Create new Project here...". In the create app dialog you first choose the type of project you want to create. For your first app choose "Android App / Hello World" here. A dialog will popup where you can define the basic information about your new app: First, choose a name for your app. Second, choose a package name of your app. Your package name must be unique across all packages installed on the Android system. For this reason, it's generally best if you use a name that begins with the reverse domain name of your organization or publisher entity. Finally, tap "Create" to make AIDE generate your new app project. An app project contains all the files that comprise the source code for your Android app. AIDE will generate these files on your SD card. AIDE will also open two important files of your new app for editing: main.xml and MainActivity.java. By default, AIDE will create a Git repository for your new project. This behavior can be turned off in the settings. See the tutorial about Using the [Git version control system](https://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_git.html) for more info.

[image: Have a look at Detailed Images while creating appliation]

**Step:3**: Running the App Project

> Running an app project with AIDE is easy. Just select "Run" from the menu. In order to run your app, AIDE will first build an Android application package file (APK) for your app. An APK file is used to distribute and install application software onto the Android operating system. The APK file contains all of your program's code, resources, assets, certificates, and manifest file. You will see a popup showing the progress of the build.

[image]

Finally, you can run!

[image]

For more details: 
[Create a Simple app using AIDE. AIDE tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgNPo8CvDHk)

[Develop Android apps from within Android using AIDE (video)](https://www.engadget.com/2012/03/07/develop-android-using-aide-video/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to use AIDE. I want to make something like AIDE :)

Comment: But i vote up cause your great answer may help someone else :)

Comment: @Shamshirsaz.Navid Try decoding the AIDE application and you'll get the way how it works.

Comment: @KiranManiya i think i should cross-compile the toolchain my self :)

Comment: Thank you @Shamshirsaz.Navid & good luck for your creation :)